# How to start a function only when the first character input is typed? in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I saw a tutorial on youtube of how to make a speed typing game, it works fine, but the timer starts to count once the page is loaded/or the new quote is rendered. I want add a new function to make the timer start only when the first character is typed, I could make it stay in 0 with the .innerText = 0, but I'm not being able to make it start when I type the character, what is wrong with the function I created?(The renderNewQuote and startTimer functions are working well, just have to make this resetTimer function I created work)

```
function resetTimer() {
  timerElement.innerText = 0
  quoteInputElement.addEventListener('onkeydown', () => {
    onkeydown.startTimer()
  })
}
```

Edit: That's part of the original code, where I want to implement that functionally I said above:

```
async function renderNewQuote() {
  const quote = await getRandomQuote()
  quoteDisplayElement.innerHTML = ''
  quote.split('').forEach(character => {
    const characterSpan = document.createElement('span')
    characterSpan.innerText = character
    quoteDisplayElement.appendChild(characterSpan)
  })
  quoteInputElement.value = null
  resetTimer() // Here was the startTimer() function, where I changed to the one that I created
}

function resetTimer() {
  timerElement.innerText = 0
  quoteInputElement.addEventListener('input', () => {
    onkeydown.startTimer()
  })
}

let startTime
function startTimer() {
  timerElement.innerText = 0
  startTime = new Date()
  setInterval(() => {
    timer.innerText = getTimerTime()
  }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: The name of the keydown event is "keydown".  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your resetTimer() function do for example this:

```
 function resetTimer() {
    timerElement.innerText = 0
    quoteInputElement.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
        if(event.target.value.length===1) startTimer()
    })
  }
```

The solutions before haven't been working since they are missing the condition. Because of this, the startTimer() function was called over and over starting from number 0.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a wonderful event listener called **input**

```
function resetTimer() {
  timerElement.innerText = 0
  quoteInputElement.addEventListener('input', () => {
    startTimer()
  })
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, but unfortunately it's not working yet, i'll edit the question and add the other two functions also

Comment: Hey @Kyouma I just updated it, check it out